# Number of non repeating lines - unique count

Tags: bash, shell, line, unique

Here is my problem: Any number of lines of text is given from standard input.
Output: number of non repeating lines

**INPUT:**

```
She is wearing black shoes.
My name is Johny.
I hate mondays.
My name is Johny.
I don't understand you.
She is wearing black shoes.
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2
```

Answer (score 114):

You could try using uniq `man uniq` and do the following

```
sort file | uniq -u | wc -l
```

Comment: I added the `sort` command in the mix.  Nice catch...I had it out of order

Comment: in the man pages it states: Note:  'uniq'  does  not  detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.  You may want to sort the input first, or use `sort -u' without `uniq'. Also, comparisons honor the rules specified by `LC_COLLATE'. It worked also....

Comment: In my case, doing `sort file | uniq -u` gives different output than `sort -u file` for the same file. `sort -u file` gave the correct output.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I'd solve the problem:

```
... | awk '{n[$0]++} END {for (line in n) if (n[line]==1) num++; print num}'
```

But that's pretty opaque. Here's a (*slightly*) more legible way to look at it (requires bash version 4)

```
... | {
    declare -A count    # count is an associative array

    # iterate over each line of the input
    # accumulate the number of times we've seen this line
    #
    # the construct "IFS= read -r line" ensures we capture the line exactly

    while IFS= read -r line; do
        (( count["$line"]++ ))
    done

    # now add up the number of lines who's count is only 1        
    num=0
    for c in "${count[@]}"; do
        if (( $c == 1 )); then
            (( num++ ))
        fi
    done

    echo $num
}
```

Comment: on my '99 machine the awk solution worked seamlessly

Comment: @sfiore, what's a "'99 machine"?